# Scrolling a DetailViewer in SmartClient

Tags: smartgwt, smartclient

Using [SmartClient](http://www.smartclient.com/product/smartclient.jsp):

I have a VLayout composed of a DetailViewer (that monitors selection changes in a ListGrid) and a HLayout (that holds some buttons).

Now, when the user selects rows in the ListGrid, the DetailViewer "grows" and creates a Scrollbar.

In consequence the bottom HLayout is also contained in the Scrollbar. I would like to avoid this. My intention is to have the bottom HLayout always visible (i.e. the Scrollbar would contain the DetailViewer only).

How can I do this?

(Also posted [here](http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?p=71004#post71004).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set overflow:auto on the DetailViewer.

Answer (score 0):

I am pursuing that there is only one VLayout and inside it there is one HLayout (with buttons) and a DetailViewer.

Now if you want your buttons to be always visible shift buttons on the top of VLayout and set overflow property as "visible" with some height say 50.  Now second child inside VLayout should be DetailViewer with overflow property as "auto", so if required DetailViewer will show scrollbars.

Secondly, you can switch the position of HLayout and DetailViewer but do not forget to set height and overflow properties.

Thanks
shaILU